# Why the Bing Search Api is not working it just only say's subscription expired but i have 0 quotas used

Tags: c#

When ever I send a get request to the bing search (Image, Video, News & Web) it just returns that the subscription expired.

```
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2016 06:02:29 GMT
Content-Length: 83
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "error": {
    "code": "SubscriptionExpired",
    "message": "This subscription has expired."
  }
}
```

What went wrong? My quotas is 0 of 1000 queries.

Comment: You might want to ask Microsoft support instead.

Comment: As of this morning, I'm seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the bing image API has ended. I do remember reading they were ending it completely at the end of 2016. Perhaps they are jumping the gun a month early.

According to Microsoft, 'TO CONTINUE USAGE AFTER DECEMBER 15, 2016 The Azure Marketplace "Bing Search" and "Bing Search Web Results Only" API offerings will end of life on December 15, 2016. New Cognitive Services Bing Search API is available for purchase through Azure.com.'

I was able to get up and running again setting up and account at their new Azure Marketplace API.

For the full details on how to migrate your request, you should follow this guide from Microsoft:

https://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_MIGRATION_GUIDE.docx

For example, my final request for images looks like this: 'api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?$format=json&Query=%27Samford%27'

Comment: If you want to see it in action, click [link](http://rit.universitylite.com/). I used bing API to auto populate my header with a relevant image and now use Azure starting 3 days ago. If you'd like to see the whole function if it may help you, I uploaded it for you here: [link](http://www.universitylite.com/azure.txt)

Answer (score -1):

The free subscription is three months only now.